# How to parce html from wikipedia table with clean data output using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Im trying the write a script that scraps data from a wikipeadia page containing multiple tabels of Hurricane Data

Here I import the BeautifulSoup package to parce the html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
html = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Category_4_Atlantic_hurricanes").text #grabing the html from wikipedia
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib') #creating a soup object that allows for searching via tags
```

Here I use the `soup.find_all` function to select the table class. I reference the 5th table in square brackets

```
table = soup.find_all('table', class_="wikitable")[5]
```

Here I strip the header row information using a list comprehension

```
headers = [header.text.strip() for header in table.find_all('th',{'scope' :'col'})] 
rows=[]
```

Here I loop through the table row and exctract the table data and append it to the rows variable

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'): 
rows.append([val.text.encode('utf-8').rstrip() for val in row.find_all(['td', 'th'])])

data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=headers) #Creating a panads dataframe
data2 = data.drop(data.index[0]) #droping the first row as it is a dublicate of the column header
data2.head() #viewing the data frame
```

The outputs from the data frame are not very clean however for with data fields reading like `"b'Hurricane Iris'    " , "b'October\xc2\xa08\xe2\x80\x939'" , "b'948\xc2\xa0mbar (hPa; 27.99\xc2\xa0inHg)'". Does anyone have a solution that results in a data frame with cleaner data? Thanks!`

[Image of dataframe head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gqOy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` has a specific method to read HTML *tables* into `DataFrames` - it's called `pd.read_html()`.

If you run this function on your `html` variable it will return a list of `DataFrame` objects where each object is one HTML *table*.

From your code it seems like you want to grab the **sixth** HTML *table*:

```
all_tables_in_dataframes = pd.read_html(html)
the_sixth_table_as_dataframe = all_tables_in_dataframes[5]
```

You can add `header=0` to `pdf.read_html()` to set the first row as headers:

```
all_tables_in_dataframes = pd.read_html(html, header=0)
```

---

`pd.read_html()` won't always work perfectly and there are some caveats that you can read about in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html). But it generally works well for *tables* from Wikipedia, in my experience.

Comment: This is a much more effective solution. Thanks you!

Comment: no worries! don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.